# Eclipse: How to clone git over ssh with keyfile?

Tags: eclipse, git, ssh, key, egit

Hey, I am using Eclipse (while running Ubuntu 10.10) and would like to connect to a remote git. Normally I would use the egit plugin, but now I need to **connect over ssh with keyfile**.

Unfortunately egit has no "with keyfile" option, is there a way to connect to my repository with my keyfile?
Is there a "hidden" way to make Eclipse to pass parameters (-i keyfile) to ssh or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/Remote - I had to manually load my existing key in the "Key Management" tab.

Comment: I can't test this right now, but it seems as if this is the answer for my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about egit. But what you usually do is:

1. Start ssh-agent (mine is automatically started, when my window manager starts, so you have to google a bit how to setup it)
2. Run ssh-add [your key]
3. Use git over ssh as usual. It won't ask you for any passwords, since ssh-agent takes care of it.

HTH

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This works nice while accessing via shell, but eclipse/egit keeps prompting for my password anyway and won't accept an empty password.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to setup a new mac and had this issue too. I generated a new key that wasn't in the default rsa/dsa encryption format and couldn't figure out how to get ecplise to point to it. As Jayden mentioned above, there is a key management section but on the version I have installed on mac, it isn't called that. The location is a little bit different than what was described in that link too. I had to go to Eclipse -> Settings(preferences) -> General -> network connections -> SSH2. Once you open settings you can type SSH2 in the search to also locate it. Then you will see the option to specify additional ssh private keys.

It took me a bit to find this, so hoping this helps others who find this page.

my current version:
**Version: 2023-12 (4.30.0)
Build id: 20231201-2043**